# Combine column after left join

Tags: sql

How do I combine 3 returned value columns into one column based on which column is not null?

My query is:

```
SELECT val1,val2,val3
FROM db.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN db.table2 t2 ON t2.pk = t1.t2_fk
LEFT JOIN db.table3 t3 ON t3.pk = t1.t3_fk
```

Comment: use `coalesce(val1, val2, val3)`

Comment: could you explain it a little bit more detailed?
do you want to have a combination of val1 + val2 + val3? or what do you want to do, if one of the columns is empty?

Comment: Do you mean concatenation of NOT NULL vals?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What tables do the val columns come from?

Answer (score 0):

use `coalesce()`

```
SELECT coalesce(val1,val2,val3) as va
FROM db.table1 t1
left join db.table2 t2
on t2.pk = t1.t2_fk
left join db.table3 t3
on t3.pk = t1.t3_fk
```